# How to enable soft delete in laravel backpack

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

**I'm doing CRUD operation using Backpack. Now I need soft delete for that. How can I enable it.**

Answer (score 1):

Following can be done for soft delete in Laravel.

1. add a column in the table called "deleted_at" with type datetime.
2. In the Model add namespace "use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;" and Trait "use SoftDeletes;"

Example

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Backpack\CRUD\CrudTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Age extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use SoftDeletes;
```

Comment: i trying to  use the demo version of the backpack but delete is not working and this answer didn't  do any thing